# VSTS Service Endpoint with validation link

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-pipelines-build-task

Hi I Created a service endpoint reading this [VSTS Service EndPoint Tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/extend/develop/service-endpoints) and i created successfully.
When i see jenkins endpoint it has a verification link that verifies the endpoint[image]
I google too many samples but nothing relevant information. Can anyone help to achieve this.

Comment: I don't read a question? What happens when you verify the connection?

Comment: As far as I understand, you want the same "Verify connection" functionality for your custom endpoint. If that's the case, then this link might help you: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sriramb/2016/09/15/service-endpoints-data-sources/. Scroll down to the very last paragraph called "Test service endpoint". I've never tried it myself though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the data source with TestConnection name in vss-extension.json file, for example:

```
{
      "id": "service-endpoint",
      "description": "Service Endpoint type for Fabrikam connections",
      "type": "ms.vss-endpoint.service-endpoint-type",
      "targets": [ "ms.vss-endpoint.endpoint-types" ],
      "properties": {
        "name": "fabrikam",
        "displayName": "Fabrikam server connection",
        "url": {
          "displayName": "Server Url",
          "helpText": "Url for the Fabrikam server to connect to."
        },
        "dataSources": [
          { 
              "name": "TestConnection",
              "endpointUrl": "{{endpoint.url}}api/projects/index",
              "resultSelector": "jsonpath:$[*].nm" 
          },
          {
            "name": "Fabrikam Projects",
            "endpointUrl": "{{endpoint.url}}api/projects/index",
            "resultSelector": "jsonpath:$[*].nm"
          }

        ],
        "authenticationSchemes": [
          {
            "type": "ms.vss-endpoint.endpoint-auth-scheme-token"
          },
          {
            "type": "ms.vss-endpoint.endpoint-auth-scheme-basic",
            "inputDescriptors": [
              {
                "id": "username",
                "name": "Username",
                "description": "Username",
                "inputMode": "textbox",
                "validation": {
                  "isRequired": false,
                  "dataType": "string"
                }
              },
              {
                "id": "password",
                "name": "Password",
                "description": "Password",
                "inputMode": "passwordbox",
                "isConfidential": true,
                "validation": {
                  "isRequired": false,
                  "dataType": "string"
                }
              }
            ]
          }

        ],
        "helpMarkDown": "<a href=\"url-to-documentation\" target=\"_blank\"><b>Learn More</b></a>"
      }
    }
```

Comment: Hey great solution, Kudos

Comment: What if I have to invoke an api POST method in order to test the connection?